# Creating a power automate cloud flow trigger when a Microsoft Exchange email comes

Tags: email, power-automate, microsoft-exchange

Power automate cloud flow does not have a trigger to fire when an email comes to Microsoft Exchange. Is there a work around for this?

I was looking for templates but there aren't any for this.

Comment: Just to double check, you are talking about Microsoft Exchange Server, privately hosted? If that is the case I am not aware that this is possible with cloud flows. You might be able to use a desktop flow for this instead (RPA). If you are talking about Microsoft Exchange Online this is your connector to look for: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/connectors/office365/

Comment: Yes, it's privately hosted. Thanks, I'll look for another approach

Comment: An extremely pragmatic approach would be to forward the mail to the Power-Automate user account, which in that case would need an Outlook 365 account. From there you can use a trigger.